Citing specific R functions in publications?
I'm wondering how common (or uncommon) it is to cite R functions in publications. E.g. to write in a manuscript something like:

We used the 'X' function from the 'Y' package version 0.2.0 [@ref] to compute...

Where @ref points out to the actual package, not the function cited.
Most of the time, citing the package is enough, especially when also sharing the code to reproduce the analyses. In some cases, there might be functions that do things in a very specific way or multiple functions that do similar things but slightly differently though, and mentioning the exact function could make sense. I don't necessarily have a good example in mind but is it recommended to cite a specific function along with the package in this case? Do people advise against it? Is it something that you see being done in your field?
For the full context: I've many packages to cite in the project I'm working on so I made a tiny R package to automatize this process in Quarto and R Markdown. I initially implemented a way to cite any R object (e.g. function, data set, etc.) from a particular package. E.g. using fun(foo) cites the foo package when fun(foo::bar, type = "function") cites the bar function from the foo package. I'm planning on releasing the package soon and I'm now unsure if I should keep this functionality or not. When citing an R object, the package will check that the object actually exists in the corresponding package and add a preformatted string before the package citation, e.g. the 'X' function from or the 'Y' data set from. This is a cheap implementation but that could also easily be done manually so I'm trying to figure out how useful that would be in practice given that most objects used from a package are functions.

What field? Norms vary.

@Azor Ahai My field is Ecology. I've seen some rather rare mention of functions in the methods section, more often in theses than actual publications though. The field doesn't matter much since the package could be use by anyone. I'm rather trying to get an idea if citing functions is actually a thing.

The answer to your question "I'm wondering how common (or uncommon) it is to cite R functions in publications" is almost certainly field-dependent (everything is). Should everyone be? Probably, but I can't speak to fields besides my own.

Of course it's field-dependend but I'm mostly interested in what happens in your field rather than figuring out which field does it or not.

I'm not sure what the difference is between 'I'm interested in what happens in your field" vs. "figuring out which field does it or not"

I'm a fellow ecologist and do a lot of software dev, including working on/publishing R packages. It's definitely seen as acceptable in this field to include the names of functions in the manuscript, at least acceptable enough that I occasionally run across it. But I think it should be avoided in most cases. Here's my thoughts on it:

In the manuscript, you should cite the package and describe the analysis or data processing you're doing anyway. That description should already encompass whatever the functions are doing. Telling your readers what function you are using is just redundant and wastes your word count.
The complete code should ideally always be included in the SI. Writing function names in the main text is redundant with that.
It puts you in the position of now deciding what functions are important enough to include and what functions should be excluded.
The behavior of many functions can vary greatly depending on the specific inputs. Just providing a name might be meaningless without a lot more details.
The behavior of functions can change or become deprecated in the future. Citing the package version number does cover that, but not including the function name limits any effect it might have to just the SI.
Many people might be interested in the overall results and methodology of your paper but not use your particular programming language. Citing functions wastes their time/mental energy when reading. Sure, maybe not a lot if you cite one or two functions, but if you cite dozens of functions for a particularly complex analysis... Citing the packages is enough to tell someone if going to the SI will be useful for them.

The short version is that it's often redundant and has no real upside over just having the complete code in the SI.
When do I think it's a good idea to include them? There are a couple of situations I can think of off the top of my head:

Publishing a package. Here, the manuscript is about the package itself. Describing features and workflows could very well be aided by the inclusion of function names
Publishing a manuscript documenting or exploring some aspect of a package. For example, a popular package may have a bug in a function and someone might want to write a manuscript documenting the bug and how prior work has been impacted by it. Or maybe someone developed a new algorithm and wants to compare it to existing implementations.

The key point with these is that the function names aren't just being included; something about their specific functionality is important enough to write a manuscript about it.

Thanks for your detailed input. I agree with you and the more I think about it the more I feel like citing functions is unnecessary. You made some good points with publishing a package in a journal or book. My package wouldn't be useful in that case though, because I designed it to mention a particular function together with the package citation which would be redundant. I've just put the package online here if you're interested. I'll remove the functionality to cite a function/object from a package soon.

Based upon you this comments, "I've many packages to cite in the project I'm working on so I made a tiny R package to automatize this process in Quarto and R Markdown", you might be going into the details too much.
Instead of citing all functions, I do something like:

We fit a dose-response curve using the drm function from the drc package (Ritz et al. 2015) and plotted data with the ggplot2 package(Wickham 2009) using R version 4.4.1 (R Core Team 2024). A supplement contains key model outputs and all R package version details (Supplement 1).

Then, I use a Quarto documents to render a PDF with my figures and models and include a print(sessionInfo()) to document my exact work environment for reproducibility.

Even ggplot2 is probably overkill.

Yes, that's more or less what I do too. Just to make it clear, when I say citing functions, I don't mean citing all functions, just very specific ones like drm in your example. Is it something you see regularly?

@Azor Ahai In theory you should cite all the packages used to produce the results presented in a manuscript, this includes packages to make figures. It doesn't have to be in main text but at least in the appendix. If using multiple packages from the tidyverse, the developers recommend to cite tidyverse rather than each individual package though.

@AzorAhai-him- far enough. The supplement with the all the packages is key. I have a collaborator who once had to recreate his environment and discovered in hindsight there was only a 2-3 month period when all of packages worked together on CRAN!

@AzorAhai-him- I do think it's common that citing packages for plotting and table formatting, data cleaning, loading files, and other related utilities is often left out of citation, and honestly I don't do a great job myself of comprehensively citing outside of references in the code itself, but there's some argument to be made that citation is academic currency and the creators of those packages deserve some of that currency, too.

All reasonable perspectives; I operate on the principle that the scientific bits should be cited, but that tidying and plotting lies outside of that, in the same way we don't cite the databases our data is stored in pre-analysis (at least, I've never seen that). Do the developers of mutate need citations to get tenure? | Second, methods sections would be very bogged down in irrelevant info if every package is included.

@AzorAhai-him- Look at the author list for https://joss.theoj.org/papers/10.21105/joss.01686 for example - many are/were students and academics at various levels. Some may need citations for tenure, others may need citations for the job market. Hopefully in the departments they would be applying to their software package would be sufficiently well-known that it's not as important, but not all packages are equally famous.

I don't think the ggplot2 is overkill. When you get started with stuff like this and want to learn and reproduce, the more detail someone left for you the better...

@BioBrains While an admirable goal, I don't think every paper needs to be an introductory guide to the field. We stopped citing the idea of a linear regression a long time ago, for example.

When giving a reference for an R function or package, you should cite the package, and use the citation function to find how the package author wants you to cite it. For example
citation("mgcv")

This might just give the CRAN page, or it might give a journal article, or several things.
So your suggestion

We used the 'X' function from the 'Y' package version 0.2.0 [@ref] to compute...

is good, if ref points to the package information as specified in the output from citation.

I cannot answer for R specifically as I have little experience with the citation, but I'll provide an answer with a general point of view.
But generally, if you are using a particular function, formula, algorithm, results, .... from a particular paper, you include a reference to the paper, and then when you cite it you say "We used formula X [1] to do whatever".
So your suggestion of

We used the 'X' function from the 'Y' package version 0.2.0 [@ref] to compute...

is perfectly fine when used in the text. You still want to have the "normal" reference to the whole package. You do not want your reference to point only to the function.

Yep I think that makes sense although when using a formula or method from another paper I mostly see something like we calculated X as described in paper Y. Similar to just citing a package and then let the reader find out how it was done in more details. Yes the reference points out to the package not the function. I'll edit my post to make it more clear.

@arangaca Citing only the general paper is probably more up to lazyness (I read that somewhere in there but I can't be bothered to look up where exactly). I doubt any reader would be annoyed by a more precise reference unless it makes the text less readable.

The aim of a citation is to communicate exactly what was done, with the goal of reproducibility. This means providing the code, and ideally, a reference to the environment.
I'd cite any relevant package, to be fair to the authors, but
I'd go down to the function level in two cases:

A specific function is at the core of your analysis, and it is conceivable that there are bugs. Something that exports to csv or manipulates arrays doesn't need it; a non-trivial optimisation algorithm may.
When the choice of algorithm is important. Sorting an array doesn't (in most cases), because all algorithms will give the same result; but finding peaks does, because there are many non-equivalent ways of doing it.

